# Dynamically decide which browser to use

Tags: python, browser

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically decide which web browser will open the link I clicked.
There are a few sites that I visit that work best on Iexplore and others that I prefer to open with chrome. If I set my default browser to one of these, than I'll constantly find myself opening a site with one browser, than copying the url and opening it in a new one. This happens a lot when people send me links.

I've thought of making a python script as the default browser and making a function that decides which browser should open the page. I've tried setting the script as my default browser by changing some registry keys. It seemed to work but when I try to open a site (for example writing "http://stackoverflow.com" in the run window), the url doesn't show in sys.argv.

Is there another way of finding the arguments sent to the program?

The registry keys I changed are:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\http\shell\open\command
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\https\shell\open\command
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\http\shell\open\command
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\https\shell\open\command
```

It seemed to work on windows XP but it doesn't work on 7 (the default browser is still the same...)

Comment: If possible, could you post the relevant portions of your code to help debug the problem?

Comment: this question seems more suited to superuser, so voting to move it there

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using browsers extension that emulate IE rendering instead of a homegrown solution? I believe there is one called 'ie tab' for chrome/firefox. http://www.ietab.net/

Comment: I've tried IE tab and it seems to be the current best solution, but it can create all sorts of problems when the sites try to open additional windows and other stuff. I prefer to just use the regular browser instead of a browser within a browser (browser-ception?)

Answer (score 0):

You can try build something on top of existing software which automates browser-webpage interaction, [have a look at Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619266/dynamically-decide-which-browser-to-use), maybe you can tweak it somehow to suit your needs.

But beware, the problem you are trying to solve is fairly complex and complicated, for instance consider just this: how are you going to translate your own subjective experience of a website into code? There are some objective indices, some pages simply break, but many things, such as bad css styling are difficult to asses and quantify.

EDIT: [here's a web testing framework in which you can generate your own tests in Python](http://testutils.org/sst/) It's probably easier to start with then Selenium.